# java.util.InputMismatchException while using java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, package

I'm stuck on an assignment:

> Using Netbeans, write a class called IO, in a package called util, containing the methods: `getInput(String)`, `getConsoleInput(String)`, `showMessage(String)`, and `showMessage(String, String)`. 
>   The method `getInput(String)` will be through GUI, the method `getConsoleInput(String)` will input/output through the console and return a Scanner object.
>   The `showMessage(String, String)` will accept a title for the output dialog.
>
> Then write a program using the IO class, but in a separate file and in the default package. Your program will first ask the user to enter 2 integers. If both are positive, print the sum. Then it will ask for 2 real numbers(float or double); if only one is negative, print the product of the 2 numbers. If both are negative, print the quotient. Use nested if's where possible.
>
> Output must be formatted. And all input/outputs must be done through the methods you created. All output is to be done through console and dialog.

I believe that I've written my methods correctly, but when my program codes calls them, I get multiple exceptions AFTER I respond to the dialog box.

## Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Assignment4.main(Assignment4.java:18)
```

## Java-Code:

```
public class Assignment4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = IO.getInput("Enter 2 integers");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();

        if (x > 0 && y > 0)
            IO.showMessage(String.format("The sum is: %6.2d", (x + y))); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me for being obtuse, but I've deleted the 2nd part of the program, and I'm still getting an exception in line 18. If I'm asking for 2 integers as input, then casting that back to a string, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please mark edits to the question as such and don't simply change the question without indicating so. Most of the answers below that addressed the first exception you inquired about (IllegalFormatConversionException) appear completely irrelevant now.

Comment: Will do; I apoligize.

Comment: So please edit your question now, as this is just a mess.

Answer (score 2):

The exception you are seeing is because in the bottom part of your method you are multiplying two integers not floats. The result is still an int and that int is then send as a parameter to a floating format string (6.2**f**). As the formatter expects a floating point typed parameter it bails out.

You can fix it by not reusing ints x and y , but by defining two new float typed variables.
(edit for trigger - on request)

Comment: I want to change my votes on your answers but after that time it's only possible if you've edited these. So just change your answer and inform me about, because I'm not aware if I will get an automatic notification automatic.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace points to Assignment4.main (line 20). If you look at the code that is formatting the product of the two integers, it is using the %f argument which is specific to floating numbers and not decimals (See [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html))

If the requirement is to format the results with two significand (i.e: two digits after the decimal point), then you'll want to either cast the x and y individually before operating on them, or define them as float to begin with.

Comment: Your statement about the implicit casting is correct, but does not yield the result. Casting must be done explicitly before the assignment, i.e. float product = (float) x*y; For multiplication it does not matter, but division is problematic.

Comment: @MichaelHeß You are correct. I only looked at the multiplication where it doesn't matter, but for the division it matters a lot. I'll update my answer.

Comment: you are welcome. At the end we are all here to help. ;)

Comment: I want to change my votes on your answers but after that time it's only possible if you've edited these. So just change your answer and inform me about, because I'm not aware if I will get an automatic notification automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the quite right corrections of the previous posts, the problem you're dealing with

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   ...
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>   at Assignment4.main(Assignment4.java:18)

resolves from a mismatch of your input while using the scanner (calling nextInt() but the next sequence cannot be converted to an `Integer`)

I assume that your input contains additional data between the two integers. If so you have to set a delimiter, so the scanner can porocess your input correctly (see
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String))

To get a more specific answer you have to provide your input made.

Comment: The previous answers addressed a different exception than the one shown now in the question.

Comment: OH, that's not supposed to be that way. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SO much for your help! I have figured everything out except the last line. The 4th method is overloaded, and is supposed to output to the dialog box, and if both of the numbers are negative, print the quotient, AND change the title and font. Everything works except the title/font change, and I have no clue hoe to fix it.
Here is my updated code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import Util.IO;

public class Assignment4 {
/* Calls the getInput method, requesting the user enter 2 integers,
 *then compares them to determine whether or not they're both
 *positive. If so, it returns the sum.
 */                  

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = IO.getInput("Enter 2 integers");
   int x = scan.nextInt();
   int y = scan.nextInt();
   if (x > 0 && y > 0) IO.showMessage(String.format("The sum is: %d",
            x + y)); 

   Scanner input = IO.getConsoleInput("Enter 2 real numbers");
   double b = input.nextDouble();
   double c = input.nextDouble();
   if (b < 0 && c > 0) IO.showMessage( String.format
   ( "The product is: %5.3f", (b*c)));
   else if (b > 0 && c <0) IO.showMessage( String.format
   ( "The product is: %5.3f", (b*c)));
   /*calls the overloaded showMessage method and displays the output 
    *to both the console and the dialog box, and changes the title
    *and font of the dialog box.
    */
    else if (b < 0 && c < 0) IO.showMessage( String.format
    ("The quotient is: %5.3f",("Quotient"),(b/c)));

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

x, y is int type, so using %d substitute for %6.2d

Comment: I want to change my votes on your answers but after that time it's only possible if you've edited these. So just change your answer and inform me about, because I'm not aware if I will get an automatic notification automatic.